# What's the right way to use filters with transclusion in directives?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to apply a filter to the transcluded text in my directive but I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. A working copy of idea is at the following link but I feel I'm sorting of cheating by using the compile function to get at the transcluded text. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5mZb/1/).

```
angular.module("MyApp").directive('highlighter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            phrase: '@',
            text: '@'
        },
        template: '<span ng-bind-html-unsafe=" text | highlight:phrase:false "></span>',
        compile: function (elem, attr, transclude) {
            transclude(elem, function (clone) {
                // grab content and store in text attribute
                var txt = clone[0].textContent;
                attr.text = txt;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way to do would be http://jsfiddle.net/3vknn/, I guess.

```js
angular.module("MyApp").directive('highlighter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            phrase: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $filter) {
            $scope.highlight = $filter('highlight');
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch('phrase', function(phrase) {
                var html = scope.highlight( elem.text(), phrase );
                elem.html( html );
            });
        }
    };
});
```